# Read JAVA text file and get total for each ID

Tags: java

I'm a Java beginner.. So please keep that in mind when answering this question.
I have a basic knowledge of Java but don't have a clue how to start this?

(I know this is not a general question. But I can't wrap my head around this)

I have a text file like this

```
ID AMOUNT

001 20.20
002 10.20
003 11.10
003 15.20
002 10.56
001 42.52
001 45.00
004 94.36
005 86.25
005 45.36
004 12.66
006 45.36
006 123.32
002 125.22
001 85.22
```

I need to generate a out put file with total value for each ID

Example -

```
001 192.94
002 145.98......
```

I'm able to read line by line using JAVA scanner and while loop..

Please give me a simple code to do this...

Comment: There's a function `sum()` it will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm able to read line by line

Then

1. Create a `Map<Integer, Double>` that will hold your values
2. Read line by line then use `String.split` to split your string by whitespaces to get the id and the amount
3. Parse the id as an `Integer` and the amount as a `Double`
4. Search for the id in your map. If it already exists get the amount to the specified id and add the new amount to it
5. Otherwise add a new entry that will have the new id and the amount

Answer (score 1):

Will give you a hint, read from text file using InputStream, Put ID in a map key, and value in value, upon getting same key again, retrieve old value, add new value and put in map again.

Now, you should be able to figure out as you said you have basic java knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

1) Read the file using Scanner.

2) Split the line using String.split

3) Use a dataStructure like a Hashmap to store key,value pairs. 
The key looks unique to me. If so, add the next available value.

[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Note: You can expect to get best guidelines to your question, but No one is going to 'write' code for you!